# Merge file without data loss using FFmpeg inside of WASM

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-wasm

Edit: I'm rewriting this entire question

Goal: To reconstruct a video from its pieces/chunks from a network stream inside of an `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` worker

Problems:

1. Video chunks/pieces which come after the first piece/chunk are reported by `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` to have invalid data, as seen in the log below:

```json
{
  "type": "stderr",
  "message": "video-0_chunk-1.part: Invalid data found when processing input"
}
```

2. How would I merge these chunks/pieces to reconstruct the full video using `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` (after solving the first issue above)

My current code situation:

1. For merging the video pieces

```js
const constructFile = async (chunks: Uint8Array[], queueId: number) => {
  await Promise.all(
    chunks.map(async (chunk, index) => {
      const chunkFile = `video-${queueId}_chunk-${index}`;
      await ffmpeg.writeFile(chunkFile, chunk);

      // Return information about newly created file
      ffmpeg.exec(["-i", chunkFile]);
    })
  );
};
```

I'm reading the logs/output for

```js
ffmpeg.exec(['-i', chunkFile])
```

using

```js
ffmpeg.on('log', (log) => console.log(log))
```

2. For fetching the videos using streams

```js
await useFetch(Capacitor.convertFileSrc(file.path), {
  responseType: "stream",

  onResponse: async ({ response }) => {
    if (response.body) {
      const reader = response.body.getReader();

      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();

        if (done) break;
        file.chunks.push(value);
      }
      reader.releaseLock();
    }
  },
});
```

**Note:** file.chunks is linked to a reactive value which is passed to `constructFile()` when initialized

These are the logs I get from the code currently above:

```
chunk-4OF65L5M.js:2710 <Suspense> is an experimental feature and its API will likely change.
(index):298 native App.addListener (#25407936)
(index):298 native FilePicker.pickVideos (#25407937)
(index):272 result FilePicker.pickVideos (#25407937)
(index):298 native VideoEditor.thumbnail (#25407938)
(index):272 result VideoEditor.thumbnail (#25407938)
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like repla…3.1.40 (5c27e79dd0a9c4e27ef2326841698cdd4f6b5784)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --…e-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: "Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video-0_chunk-0':"}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  Metadata:'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    major_brand     : mp42'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    minor_version   : 0'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    compatible_brands: isommp42'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    creation_time   : 2022-11-29T14:46:32.000000Z'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  Duration: 00:00:51.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 81 kb/s'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 …6], 259 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    Metadata:'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      creation_time   : 2022-11-29T14:46:32.000000Z'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/29/2022.'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0…706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '    Metadata:'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      creation_time   : 2022-11-29T14:46:32.000000Z'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/29/2022.'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'At least one output file must be specified'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'Aborted()'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like repla…3.1.40 (5c27e79dd0a9c4e27ef2326841698cdd4f6b5784)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --…e-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'video-0_chunk-1: Invalid data found when processing input'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'Aborted()'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like repla…3.1.40 (5c27e79dd0a9c4e27ef2326841698cdd4f6b5784)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --…e-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'video-0_chunk-2: Invalid data found when processing input'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'Aborted()'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like repla…3.1.40 (5c27e79dd0a9c4e27ef2326841698cdd4f6b5784)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --…e-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'video-0_chunk-3: Invalid data found when processing input'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'Aborted()'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'ffmpeg version 5.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like repla…3.1.40 (5c27e79dd0a9c4e27ef2326841698cdd4f6b5784)'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --…e-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: '  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'video-0_chunk-4: Invalid data found when processing input'}
Processing.vue:135 {type: 'stderr', message: 'Aborted()'}
```

**Notes:**

1. The sections which start with `Processing.vue` come from the logging system I've setup.
2. The pieces/chunks gotten from the network where stored in exactly the same order in which they came
3. If you've seen the old question, the `ReferenceError` happens as a result of HMR by Vite

   1. Similar to this, some logs were repeated twice because I was actively changing some things and the component had to rerun from the start

**Summary:** If my problem is still not clear, you could provide another way of fetching a large file (video) from a network, loading the file into memory and passing the file data to `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` for further processing

Comment: 29876043 is the expected sum of chunks? what is the real output? or you expect a final file 29876043 (bytes ?) long but get 155117 bytes?
and how do you call those functions? how chunkify and writeFileInMemory are related?

Comment: @mortalis I've provided the full context 

Comment: Uh, I really need help with this

Comment: Some notes regarding the log: there's `ReferenceError`, maybe it's something critical that doesn't let processing, though it's not clear at which stage it happens. Then, not clear what logs come from your code and what from `ffmpeg.on('log')`, maybe you could add some prefix to distinguish those. And why the logs are repeated? For example you have `Total size: ` repeated twice and seeing for example `Input #0` it repeats 3 times, so ffmpeg commands are run 3 times, and the last 2 of them seem to run on the same file, is it expected?

Comment: And besides, what exactly are you trying to do, merge 2 video files, merge video chunks from a list of chunks, split a video to chunks and merge them...? From the text it's not clear, I think the first part of a question should start with the clear description of the goal you're trying to achieve. Because "I have this code" doesn't explain the problem by itself you know? :)

Comment: As a general rule for large code that has problems is to divide the problem into smaller pieces and detect which part is critical. Or start from something small and controlable, and then build up until you reach the original problem.

Comment: `Impossible to open 'video-1_chunk-1.part'"` that seems to be another problem.
Can you run just a local version of ffmpeg and try to perform the conversion you need? Without an intermediate layer like typescript/node. Possibly reducing the number of chunks/input size to keep it more controlable.

Comment: @mortalis I can't run a local version of ffmpeg on the device sadly, it's meant to run inside Android in a WebView. I've edited the question to be much more specific and I've reduce the factors to a smaller file, I hope this makes this question solvable. Thanks for your patience

Comment: It's been a week and I still haven't found a solution

Comment: By local version I mean a PC ffmpeg.exe, if on Windows for example.

Comment: This is meant to run on an Android WebView, since I'm using Capacitor and Ionic. I could have made a plugin for this, but I have a general idea of Java and don't know how I'll do this in it.

Comment: Are you trying to combine chunks from a single MediaRecorder recording? If not, what is the source of the video chunks? What type of file is the 'large network file'?